# Integrate JEE with JSE

Tags: java, jsf

I have a Java EE application, running under JBoss, i'm using JSF technology, my application have a point that i need receive a Credit Card number.

In other side i have a Java SE application that read a Credit Card number using PINPAD machine:

[image]

My big problem is: The user clicks in a button on JSF applicaton (Read Credit Card button) and i need call this Java SE Application to read this Credit Card and after pass this number to JSF again. So i think in some solutions:

1) Connect JSF and JAva SE application in same database. Register events from JSF to JSE Application through database. My JSE Application will listener for new events in database. 
2) Connect from JSF to JSE Application through WebService. But i will need call JSE Application WebService, this is possible in a JSE App ?

So, if you guys have another better solution , please let me know.

Comment: Just curious, shouldn't the java se application be initiating the call to jsf app server with the card details instead of jsf app server calling the java se app ?

Comment: The problem is: My Java SE need some command to start this window, and who commands it is JSF